# Change login failure message

Tags: debian, configuration, login, pam

I want to change login failure message in Debian 8 x64

```
login: root
password:
login incorrect - /this/
login:
```

Can you tell me how to do that?

P.S.: and for more - how to set number of login attempts? Something like: 3 failed attempts and then 15min cooldown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here: https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/login.c

it is hardcoded at line #834:

```
(void) puts ("");
(void) puts (_("Login incorrect"));
```

So you have to modify the source then compile login.c for your system.

ps: one question per post

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers, as links tend to die. Besides, while the code might contain an actual answer, it would probably be better to provide an explanation here.